# How to configure Windows Firewall to access Spring Framework application while debugging in Intellij?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, windows-firewall

How can I set up Windows Firewall rule to allow connections to my Java application started in IntelliJ debugger?

My problem is that I have no idea which application I have to allow in Windows Firewall.

Comment: Application would be `java.exe` from the JDK configured in the project. There are millions of documents how to allow an app via firewall by port or by process. What exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I got this, but thanks for information about `java.exe` process. Sorry about asking such trivial question. I thought that current version of Windows has been castrated from "normal firewall" configuration, like it was with many features (context menu taskbar for example).

Answer (score 1):

So, I had to open advanced firewall configuration. Easiest way is to open it from console:

```
wf.msc
```

And then just add new Incoming Rule, choose Port and other options as desired.